# Azure Group added to Local Machine Administrators Group

Tags: permissions, azure, azure-activedirectory

What I am aiming to do is add an Azure Group **"Local_Admins" SID:b42afbaf-7e4d-4d1b-b2c1-39630ccec6b2** to the local Administrator group on devices.

I know there is a solution for adding users to the local admin group and that works fine, but adding and removing users from that group constantly is extremely undesirable and thus I would prefer to be able to add users to an Azure group to have the same effect.

**I attempted the following:**

```
net localgroup administrators "AzureAD\LocalAdmins" /add
```

> Result: There is no such global user or group AzureAD\LocalAdmins

```
net localgroup administrators "AzureAD\Local_Admins" /add
```

> Result: There is no such global user or group AzureAD\Local_Admins

```
net localgroup administrators "AzureAD\b42afbaf-7e4d-4d1b-b2c1-39630ccec6b2" /add
```

> Result: Syntax Error

```
net localgroup administrators "b42afbaf-7e4d-4d1b-b2c1-39630ccec6b2" /add
```

> Result: Syntax Error

If anyone has a good solution for this issue, I would love to hear from them.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to leverage **Microsoft Intune (Microsoft Endpoint Manager)**

See here: https://www.inthecloud247.com/add-an-azure-ad-group-to-the-local-administrators-group-with-microsoft-intune/

> In that post I already showed how the local administrators group on a
> Windows 10 machine can be managed with Microsoft Intune (Microsoft
> Endpoint Manager), but I only showed how to add Azure AD user accounts
> to the administrators group.
>
> But as described on Microsoft docs, also Azure AD Groups are
> supported;
>
> > The member SID can be an user account or a group in AD, Azure AD, or
> > on the local machine.